# Powershell Migration script 2013 on prem to Office 365

Tags: 2013, powershell, office-365, sharepoint-on-prem

I am building an on prem sp2013 intranet with the option of putting it in the cloud in the future. What I am thinking is writing some powershell script to add the pagelayouts change the welcome page add content types to certain page libraries etc. Will I be able to use this same powershell script to migrate everything to office 365 or will I need to change it drastically for it to work for office 365? is there another cost free way of doing this?

Comment: You'll be able to accomplish some of what you wish using CSOM.  If you planned on using SSOM, you'll be out of luck.